# Representing the Basel Series Geometrically

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose each term of the [Basel series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ is represented as a square of side length $\frac{1}{n}$ placed along the x-axis.

[image: basel]

The Basel area is finite $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ but the total length along the x-axis that these squares cover is an infinite [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$.

**Question**

How can a finite area be distributed along an infinite length?

Comment: I think more than anything you’re using words to confuse yourself. “how can a finite area be distributed along an infinite length” is a (mathematically) meaningless phrase, and it doesn’t quantify something being larger than another, nor does it indicate any contradiction. Imagine the (very rapdily converging geometric) series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$. You can think of this as adding up areas of rectangles of height $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and base length $1$. This is a finite area spread over an infinite length. Does this example confuse you as well?

Comment: Your example makes sense to me. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: If you're interested, 3blue1brown made a geometric proof for the Basel problem. https://m.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4&v=d-o3eB9sfls&embeds_referring_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&source_ve_path=MjM4NTE&feature=emb_title